# I want to copy table contained from one database and insert onto another database table

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to copy a table's schema as well as the data within that table to another database table in another database on a live server.  How could I do this?

Comment: use two database connections and read table structure from one and run that query in to other

Comment: Are these databases on separate mysql instances or the same one?  Different instances could be setup with replication if this is a continuous process.

Comment: @Nick my databases are on different mysql instances. Could you explain how to copy it?

Answer (score 220):

If you want to copy a table from one Database to another database , You can simply do as below.

```
CREATE TABLE db2.table LIKE db1.table;
INSERT INTO db2.table SELECT * FROM db1.table;
```

Comment: Great solution if the table has no foreign key constraints. I used this for making a copy of an entire database instead of just one table. For that I'd recommend using mysqldump command.

Comment: MySQL can now store table data in individual files (and the frm files are too per table). This approach would no doubt work, but with huge databases it is slow. Is there another way maybe?

Comment: This only works if the databases are on the same server.

Answer (score 10):

or just CREATE TABLE db2.table SELECT * FROM db1.table in MySQL 5

Comment: This does not copy things such as index. It merely creates a table based on a set of tuples. You probably don't want to do this.

Comment: Yeah this query does not copies indexe

Answer (score 4):

In BASH you can do:

```
mysqldump database_1 table | mysql database_2
```

Answer (score 2):

CREATE TABLE db2.table_new AS SELECT * FROM db1.table_old

Answer (score 2):

If you just want Structure to be copied simply use

`CREATE TABLE Db_Name.table1 LIKE DbName.table2;`

Ps > that will not copy schema and data

Answer (score 1):

simply use -

CREATE TABLE DB2.newtablename SELECT * FROM DB1.existingtablename;

Answer (score 0):

In Commandline:

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u username -ppassword [SCHEMA] --tables [TABLE] | mysql -h otherhost -u username -ppassword [SCHEMA2]
```

This will copy table inside SCHEMA on localhost to SCHEMA2 on otherhost.

localhost and otherhost are just hostname and might be same or different.