# Copying tables from one db to another if they do not exist in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How would I copy all tables from database A to database B that do not exist in database B? Both databases are on the same server.

Thanks for ideas :)!

Comment: you want to do it in single command or just want to do this activity....

Comment: A single command would be perfect.

Comment: max tables are matching or non-matching...

Comment: Why can't you use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8754721/430112). Just use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` to avoid duplication

Comment: You can Accomplish using mysql dump.[Reference Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/downloading-mysql-dump-from-command-line

Comment: You Can accomplish using mysqldump.[Reference link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/downloading-mysql-dump-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script, which will copy only those tables, don't exist on target db.

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=root
PASS=root123
SOURCE_DB=db1
TARGET_DB=db2

TBL=`mysql -u$USER -p$PASS -e"SET group_concat_max_len=102400;SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.table_name SEPARATOR ' ') FROM information_schema.tables a LEFT JOIN information_schema.tables b ON a.table_name=b.table_name AND b.table_schema='$TARGET_DB' AND b.table_type='BASE TABLE' WHERE a.table_schema='$SOURCE_DB' AND b.table_name IS NULL AND a.table_type='BASE TABLE';"`

mysqldump --single-transaction -u$USER -p$PASS $SOURCE_DB $TBL | mysql -u$USER -p$PASS $TARGET_DB
```

change root to whatever your user

root123 with that user password

db1 to your source DB

db2 to your target DB