# How to copy-paste data from one table to another in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-connection, relational-database

I have crate a db in MySQL which has a lot of tables. I want the value of one table to be automatically saved on another table too.

For example I write something on: table1.lastname, I want this to be also stored in table2.lastname .

How is this called and how I can do that with PHP My Admin?

Comment: you can do this by triggers

Comment: Any further information??

Comment: If you tell us the purpose, some one could possibly provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name LIKE old_table_name

Create trigger after_insert on new_table  
like this

CREATE TRIGGER `AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `new_table_name` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

insert into new_table_name (column_names) values (column_values) ;

END
```

Comment: Hello,

I want to copy the lastname from db1 to lastname in db2.
Can you please tell me how to syntax this?

Comment: SET database2.table1.columnA TO database1.table1.columnA WHERE database2.id = database1.id

Comment: Thank you! 

And where exactly do i run this? Just like a simple SQL query?

Comment: Sorry but i received an error!!  It is my fault!
I want the table1.lastname to copied to table2.lastname!

SAME DATABASE different Tables!

Comment: insert into table2 (lastname) 
select lastname from table1;

Answer (score 0):

For first you must create table for data store.
Then you must create trigger on wanted table for catch event and insert data in early created table.

Answer (score -1):

This will do what you want:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (lastname)
SELECT lastname
FROM table1
```

If you want to include all rows from table1. Otherwise you can add a WHERE statement to the end if you want to add only a subset of table1.

I hope this helps.

---

If the table doesn't exist, you can create one with the same schema like so:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 LIKE table1;
```

Then, to copy the data over:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1
```

Or If the tables have different structures you can also:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (`col1`,`col2`) SELECT `col1`,`col2` FROM table1;
```

EDIT: to constrain this..

```
INSERT INTO table2 (`col1_`,`col2_`) SELECT `col1`,`col2` FROM 
table1 WHERE `foo`=1
```

Comment: Hello,

So far i have just create the tables in MySQL. Nothing else, 
How can i do that?

Comment: He isn't looking for a PHP solution, he probably wants an SQL solution, to make it automatic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754607/i-want-to-copy-table-contained-from-one-database-and-insert-onto-another-databas